# Is there an efficient way to determine if a sum of floats will be order invariant?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Due to precision limitations in floating point numbers, the order in which numbers are summed can affect the result.

```py
>>> 0.3 + 0.4 + 2.8
3.5
>>> 2.8 + 0.4 + 0.3
3.4999999999999996
```

This small error can become a bigger problem if the results are then rounded.

```py
>>> round(0.3 + 0.4 + 2.8)
4
>>> round(2.8 + 0.4 + 0.3)
3
```

I would like to generate a list of random floats such that their rounded sum does not depend on the order in which the numbers are summed.  My current brute force approach is O(n!).  Is there a more efficient method?

```py
import random
import itertools
import math


def gen_sum_safe_seq(func, length: int, precision: int) -> list[float]:
    """
    Return a list of floats that has the same sum when rounded to the given
    precision regardless of the order in which its values are summed.
    """
    invalid = True
    while invalid:
        invalid = False
        nums = [func() for _ in range(length)]
        first_sum = round(sum(nums), precision)
        for p in itertools.permutations(nums):
            if round(sum(p), precision) != first_sum:
                invalid = True
                print(f"rejected {nums}")
                break

    return nums

for _ in range(3):
    nums = gen_sum_safe_seq(
        func=lambda :round(random.gauss(3, 0.5), 3),
        length=10,
        precision=2,
    )
    print(f"{nums} sum={sum(nums)}")
```

For context, as part of a programming exercise I'm providing a list of floats that model a measured value over time to ~1000 entry-level programming students.  They will sum them in a variety of ways.  Provided that their code is correct, I'd like for them all to get the same result to simplify checking their code.  I do not want to introduce the complexities of floating point representation to students at this level.

Comment: If precision is important I probably wouldn't use floats, but instead use something like the `Fraction` class which can maintain precision.

Comment: The question itself is a bit shaky.  First, it depends very much on the underlying floating point representation and implementation.  Second, even if your platform uses 64-bit IEEE floating point numbers, the result of a floating point operation may still vary depending on how those operations are implemented.  For example, many implementations have floating point registers that are, say, 80 bits, which are used for in-register floating point operations.  If you call a Python function that's coded in C, it's possible that those registers may be used, resulting in increased precision.

Comment: @flakes I understand that there are better choices than floats when precision is important.  Even with floats, I could use `math.fsum` to get the "right" result regardless of order.  Unfortunately, I actually need a list of floats where the result of the builtin `sum` function will be the same regardless of order.

Comment: Why not just level with the students about floating point being complicated, and have them test within some small `epsilon`?

Comment: @btilly I've tried introducing some floating point issues before.  I've found that at this level, it distracts students from the primary learning objectives.  My goal is to make the correctness of their code more easily testable when grading by generating safer test cases.

Comment: If your goal is to not get into the semantics of data-precision, but the results must be precise, why even use floats for the example? Surely you could rework the assignment to work with integers if that was the goal.

Comment: @flakes There are endless alternative possiblities, but I found this math/programming problem interesting.  Im still hoping to find better algorithms.

Comment: @JohnCole I would recommend then that you write epsilon-tolerant use cases. They don't need to think about it. As for the math problem, the best I found was `O(n * 2^n)`. But I expect that better is possible.

Comment: Can't you just generate a random sequence of floats that doesn't have a sum between say x.495 and x.505?

Comment: Are you only considering linear summation like ((a+b)+c)+d, or also divide&conquer summation like (a+b)+(c+d)? I'd have plenty of other suggestions/questions, but seems like you're determined to use your way and just want the question answered as-is...

Comment: Is length 10 what you actually want, or what other length do you really want?

Comment: Btw, somewhat [opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69192991/12671057) question, looking for *different* sums. Might find something useful in the answers/comments/chat there.

Comment: What's the student exercise? Just to sum the given numbers? That seems odd. Or do something else with them before summing? That could affect the sums.

Comment: You generate numbers rounded to *three* decimals but then compute/check sums rounded to only *two* decimals. Why? Why not use the same rounding for both? That would likely solve the issue.

Comment: @SimonGoater This is a great idea.  Given a list `nums` and that `s = sum(nums)*10**precision`, avoid any cases where `math.isclose(s - int(s), 0.5)`

Comment: @KellyBundy I hadn't even considered divide and conquer summation, but ideally they would sum to the same rounded result regardless. The objective of the exercise is for students to practice indexing and slicing lists.  They need to extract certain elements, calculate the average, then display the results.  Most of the slices have a length of 10.  In this SO question I'm rounding to one less digit of precision than the generated numbers because the averages should be expressed to the same precision as the values being averaged, and the length of the lists is usually 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not that I know of, but a *practical* approach is to use `math.fsum()` instead. While some platforms are perverse nearly beyond repair, on most platforms `fsum()` returns the infinitely-precise result subject to a single rounding error at the end. Which means the final result is independent of the order in which elements are given. For example,

```py
>>> from math import fsum
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> for p in permutations([0.3, 0.4, 2.8]):
...     print(p, fsum(p))
(0.3, 0.4, 2.8) 3.5
(0.3, 2.8, 0.4) 3.5
(0.4, 0.3, 2.8) 3.5
(0.4, 2.8, 0.3) 3.5
(2.8, 0.3, 0.4) 3.5
(2.8, 0.4, 0.3) 3.5
```

Python's `fsum()` docs go on to point [to slower ways](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/393090/) that are more robust against perverse platform quirks.

### Arguably silly

Here's another approach: fiddle the numbers you generate, clearing enough low-order bits so that no rounding of any kind is ever needed no matter how an addition tree is arranged. I haven't thought hard about this - it's not worth the effort ;-) For a start, I haven't thought about negative inputs at all.

```py
def crunch(xs):
    from math import floor, ulp, ldexp
    if any(x < 0.0 for x in xs):
        raise ValueError("all elements must be >= 0.0")
    target_ulp = ldexp(ulp(max(xs)), len(xs).bit_length())
    return [floor(x / target_ulp) * target_ulp
            for x in xs]
```

Then, e.g.,

```py
>>> xs = crunch([0.3, 0.4, 2.8])
>>> for x in xs:
...     print(x, x.hex())
0.29999999999999893 0x1.3333333333320p-2
0.3999999999999986 0x1.9999999999980p-2
2.799999999999999 0x1.6666666666664p+1
```

The decimal values are "a mess", because, from the hex values, you can see that the *binary* values reliably have enough low-order 0 bits to absorb any shifts that may be needed during a sum. The order of summation makes no difference then:

```py
>>> for p in permutations(xs):
...     print(p, sum(p))
(0.29999999999999893, 0.3999999999999986, 2.799999999999999) 3.4999999999999964
(0.29999999999999893, 2.799999999999999, 0.3999999999999986) 3.4999999999999964
(0.3999999999999986, 0.29999999999999893, 2.799999999999999) 3.4999999999999964
(0.3999999999999986, 2.799999999999999, 0.29999999999999893) 3.4999999999999964
(2.799999999999999, 0.29999999999999893, 0.3999999999999986) 3.4999999999999964
(2.799999999999999, 0.3999999999999986, 0.29999999999999893) 3.4999999999999964
```

and

```py
>>> import random, math
>>> xs = [random.random() * 1e3 for i in range(100_000)]
>>> sum(xs)
49872035.43787267
>>> math.fsum(xs) # different
49872035.43787304
>>> sum(sorted(xs, reverse=True)) # and different again
49872035.43787266
>>> ys = crunch(xs) # now fiddle the numbers
>>> sum(ys)  # and all three ways are the same
49872035.43712826
>>> math.fsum(ys)
49872035.43712826
>>> sum(sorted(ys, reverse=True))
49872035.43712826
```

The good news is that this is obviously linear-time in the number of inputs. The bad news is that more and more trailing bits have to be thrown away, the higher the dynamic range across the inputs, and the more inputs there are.

Comment: I think this might be the way to go. I'm testing the results of student code submissions with randomly generated lists.  The the builtin `sum` could be replaced with `math.fsum` before running their code.  The results may differ from what they produced locally, but would match the expected value during testing.

Comment: @JohnCole - you'll still run into a problem with explicit addition, where student's didn't use `sum()`

Comment: See edit for another approach that should be insensitive to any way whatsoever of doing the sum.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a
[numeric error analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis);
there is a rich literature on this.
In your example you found the
[relative error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error)
was unacceptably large.
Plus, you're cramming infinite repeating fractions
into a 53-bit mantissa, with predictable truncation issues.
Adding numbers of different magnitudes tends to cause trouble.
Here, `2.8` is more than 8x `0.3`, so we risk losing three bits of precision.

You're making this problem much too hard.
Simply use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) values.
Or do the equivalent: scale your random floats by
some large number, perhaps `1e9`, and truncate to integer.
Now you're summing integers, with no repeating fractional digits,
so we're back to being able to rely on commutativity and associativity.
Remember to scale sums appropriately when reporting the results.

What you want is "math".
What you'll get is a "machine representation".
So choose a representation that is a good fit for your use case.

EDIT

Oh, the educational context is illuminating.
Avoiding negative round-off errors is crucial.

Simply add `epsilon = 2 ** -50` to all those `round( ..., 3)`
figures being summed.
With epsilon big enough to turn even the negative rounding errors
into positive terms, for N numbers with average of `mean`,
your FP sum will be approximately `N * mean + N * epsilon`,
and then the final rounding operation trims the accumulated error.
We exploit the facts that input values are in a defined range and N is small, so lots of zero bits
separate those two terms.

The naive sum of three-digit quantities is `d1 + err1 + d2 + err2 + ... + dN + errN`, where the errors are `+` or `-` rounding errors that come from truncating a repeating fraction at 53 bits.
Separating them gives `d1 + ... + dN + N * random_var_with_zero_mean`.
I am proposing `d1 + err1 + eps  +  d2 + err2 + eps + ...` which is `d1 + ... + dN + N * eps + small_random_error`.
In particular, `eps` ensures that we *only* add positive errors
as we accumulate, and by "small" I mean `small_random_error < N * eps`.

```
from itertools import permutations

eps = 2 ** -50  # -52 suffices, but -50 is more obvious during debugging
nums = [round(random.gauss(3, 0.5), 3) + eps  for _ in range(10)]
print(expected := round(sum(nums), 3))

for perm in permutations(nums):
    assert round(sum(perm), 3) == expected
```

---

Assume positive values, e.g. uniform draws from the unit interval.
Then standard Numeric Analysis advice is to
first order the values from smallest to largest,
and *then* sum them.

If your students will distribute the summation over K hosts,
they should walk the sorted values with stride of K.

If we don't need very tight error bounds,
then histogram estimates can save a big-Oh `log N` factor,
or can even let you begin computations after
a "taste the prefix" operation which takes constant time.

Comment: For context, I'm providing a list of floats that models a measured value over time to ~1000 entry-level programming students.  They will sum them in a variety of ways.  I'd like for them all to get the same result to simplify checking their code.  I can generate acceptable lists, but it is quite slow.

Comment: Adding a small positive `epsilon` to each "three digit decimal" suffices for stable final roundoff. Downside is it's user-visible. Upside is your students should probably learn that "FP roundoff is a concern." Cooking up a special dataset that hides the issue feels too far from CS, too close to magic.

Comment: I'm not convinced of that fix. Adding two numbers can turn a positive error into a negative error.

Comment: For example [0.01+0.02](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P1FHIUnBVsFAz8BQB0QacaXlFylUKGTmKYCkdBQStZOsuBSAoKAoM69EQ11Vz9ggTV1BVaFC8/9/AA).

Comment: You changed their rounding. They round the sums to **two** decimals, not **three**. As I commented under the question, I think using the same rounding like that would likely already solve the issue. No other things like your eps-adding required.

Comment: [AssertionError](https://tio.run/##TZDRTsMwDEXf8xVX4iUdZRqthsakfglCqF3cEonEUZwg@PqSrAORF0fyvce@Dt/pnX1/CnFdrQscE@LoDTu1lb0QGf349NwoNUd2sIliYv4Q3OSBostpTJa9KEVBMKDDboeH4wG4K6WD5Hm2F5IWU07XhhU4jgSePi1ngcnR@gWGprws5ad8dpX0Ejl7o2/LLGMW0X2Lw/7YtOgb3KNOxMwRb7C@Lr@QPjWvKhRg0vQV6JLI4DxgQ0l2usKLv2tqqmKtGar7f5ZNdFYobxShepk/QBVeARgG/M5Y1x8) despite your eps if I use their rounding.

Comment: Can you reference that "standard Numeric Analysis advice" to sum from largest to smallest? I thought it's the opposite, and googling with "from largest to smallest" now, I only found people saying that from smallest to largest is better.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that order matters. I retract the remark. Considering it for a moment, yeah, small to large is better, we want large values to eventually evict small value's noise. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Faster (0.3 seconds instead of your 8 seconds for length 10, and 3.4 seconds for length 12) and considers more ways to sum (not just linear like `((a+b)+c)+d`, but also divide&conquer summation like `(a+b)+(c+d)`).

The core part is the `sums` function, which computes all possible sums. First it enumerates the numbers, so it can use sets without losing duplicate numbers. Then its inner helper `sums` does the actual work. It tries all possible splits of the given numbers into a left subset and a right subset, computes all possible sums for each, and combines them.

```py
import random
import itertools
import math
import functools

def sums(nums):
    @functools.cache
    def sums(nums):
        if len(nums) == 1:
            [num] = nums
            return {num[1]}
        result = set()
        for k in range(1, len(nums)):
            for left in map(frozenset, itertools.combinations(nums, k)):
                right = nums - left
                left_sums = sums(left)
                right_sums = sums(right)
                for L in left_sums:
                    for R in right_sums:
                        result.add(L + R)
        return result
    return sums(frozenset(enumerate(nums)))
    
def gen_sum_safe_seq(func, length: int, precision: int) -> list[float]:
    """
    Return a list of floats that has the same sum when rounded to the given
    precision regardless of the order in which its values are summed.
    """
    while True:
        nums = [func() for _ in range(length)]
        rounded_sums = {
            round(s, precision)
            for s in sums(nums)
        }
        if len(rounded_sums) == 1:
            return nums
        print(f"rejected {nums}")

for _ in range(3):
    nums = gen_sum_safe_seq(
        func=lambda :round(random.gauss(3, 0.5), 3),
        length=10,
        precision=2,
    )
    print(f"{nums} sum={sum(nums)}")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVRLjtswDF1140uUyMpCHWPSoEARwEUPMKuguyAINDZlu2NLqSTPoA1ykm5m0x6qp6koOf4k0cIf8ol6fCT1--_xp62UfHv701mx_Pzv3fu6PSptQXNZqDbq_2qL2irVmIuh5ba6fItO5sEZFSjAdK2JpXuwTQRufR38ac7zCr3xHpBWLaBBGayQZbAaXbR2zrGHDMg_c2i0nZZwco7dan-ORrvpGut2GLQxG8xCaXiGWlKaJcarZDyVzU8kZIPCErjlx1ho9Quli5aMoqS5ap9qyW2tZMgogefrQJ5NXVa2pw9LH_cGQ8YDSUOkSSEysPuhZjhvuQVSAo_Efgh8y-uC23pJhsj3gaOsKS-K-BE-wJZNBPeFCIBoYvEcB_VidBqg5hZ71UME30AlSjr-YLjAg8EfMTWQr1Bpq42j6LQ_asxr4_T2_wyWX6Cpjd2JRnG7D8QXi4V_bwMB7hGgBHiQAVtxCxWnDwTDWySO8Fqho686WWABVnlnWb-g9LGGc11aJddFg8ZQSEIpXaAmBV-rOq9cexh44U2HBrj2sVss0hkzB2wQvukOR6llKOmOko6ZL8th7NQgAtuPegeml044zaeCnLGZyMVumttQ8HEUB__5eianJ92bzb7Os9E8aledWCw0fsfcOkFpQM15waLoKrF1Py59-jc9MI6u0yVrePtUcNiEBMNdlZa8MyZeJ_CQfmIJrFkybAqyZauHZEKtlyT7GIwsmjIOREmY7OQeQRxHPNyT_XV5uTb_Aw)

Comment: This is significantly better than my original approach.  And its more correct.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create random *integers*, and then divide (or multiply) them all by the same power of 2.

As long as the sum of the absolute values of the original integers fits into 52 bits, then you can add the resulting floats without any rounding errors.

Comment: That was one of my possible suggestions as well, but those numbers tend to not look nice.

Comment: random numbers tend not to look nice

Comment: They do if you round them to your liking. In their code, they round to three decimal digits, getting numbers like `3.613` I you instead round to ten binary digits (because 2¹⁰≈10³), you get `3.61328125`. So if they want numbers with three decimal digits, that's not nice. There were plenty of other suggestions in the comments, but they seem to be determined to do it their way and are really just asking for "an efficient way to determine if a sum of floats will be order invariant"...

Comment: If you're rounding the result, then you can just make sure that the sum is far enough away from the quantization boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Faster variant of my first answer, this one only checking linear summation like `((a+b)+c)+d` like you do yourself, not also divide&conquer summation like `(a+b)+(c+d))`. Takes me 0.03 seconds for length 10 and 0.12 seconds for length 12.

```py
import random
import itertools
import math
import functools

def sums(nums):
    @functools.cache
    def sums(nums):
        if len(nums) == 1:
            [num] = nums
            return {num[1]}
        result = set()
        for last in nums:
            before = nums - {last}
            before_sums = sums(before)
            _, R = last
            for L in before_sums:
                result.add(L + R)
        return result
    return sums(frozenset(enumerate(nums)))
    
def gen_sum_safe_seq(func, length: int, precision: int) -> list[float]:
    """
    Return a list of floats that has the same sum when rounded to the given
    precision regardless of the order in which its values are summed.
    """
    while True:
        nums = [func() for _ in range(length)]
        rounded_sums = {
            round(s, precision)
            for s in sums(nums)
        }
        if len(rounded_sums) == 1:
            return nums
        print(f"rejected {nums}")

for _ in range(3):
    nums = gen_sum_safe_seq(
        func=lambda :round(random.gauss(3, 0.5), 3),
        length=10,
        precision=2,
    )
    print(f"{nums} sum={sum(nums)}")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVRLjtswDN105VMQWVmoE0waFCgCeDAHmFXQXRAEGpv-FLaUSvIM2iDLnqKb2bSH6mlKSo4_M9HCHz6KfHyk9Pvv6YertHp9_dO5Yvnl34dfdXvSxoGRKtdt1P_VDo3TurFXQytddf0uOpUFMMqxANu1Nlb0ENsIaD0M-CqTWYXeeMuRV11AgypYIU1hPUK89gQcIAXGZ4BB1xkFZwL268MlGu22axztsOhiMZgLbaCRlgpTPtY8yxMSjn0aWMKZXS83XI5cAgfnSoJJzNyOCewI5_0zO-d_5OSTOHMOI_mVzPP4ET7CTkzK8uUGh2hi8UwKo3-i4oqRKkAjHQZFRYjg21Si4rRHKwvKj99jblPC6peu2hI3l8DJYFbbWiv_L2B5D01t3b5otHSHQHixWPj3LhCQ3gN0Ad7Jgqukg0ryB4KVLTJHeKmQ6OtO5ZiD0x4s62dUPtaQl8oqpckbtJZDspc2ORqW7qWqs4om08KzbDq0II2P3WK-mjEjxwbhq-lwlFiFxu256Fj4fhw5KI19iXEQQRxGvQPTa7_P89ljMLYTucS7ZlsOPg78gF_eTv40060T0Pd5dgBOhroTFwuD3zBzJCgfA3tZiCh6U9imP2p9-e9mYDwgpEvayPYpl7ANBYYbYVXKztp4k8Dd6rNIYCOSYVOQLV3fJRNqvSTpp2AU0ZRxIMrCpGd6BHGIeLiN-kvpejn9Bw)